# Akka messaging mechanisms by example

Tags: routes, akka, dispatcher, event-bus

I have a fair amount of Apache Camel (routing/mediation/orchestation engine; lightweight ESB) experience and am racking my brain trying to understand the difference between Akka:

- Dispatchers (`Dispatcher`, `PinnedDispatcher`, `CallingThreadDispatcher`)
- Routers
- Pools
- Groups
- Event Buses

According to the docs:

**Dispatchers** are:

> ...is what makes Akka Actors “tick”, it is the engine of the machine so to speak.

But that doesn't really explain what a dispatcher is or what it's relationship to an actor is.

**Routers** are:

> Messages can be sent via a router to efficiently route them to destination actors, known as its routees. A Router can be used inside or outside of an actor, and you can manage the routees yourselves or use a self contained router actor with configuration capabilities. But it sounds an awful lot like a dispatcher.

**Pools** are:

> [A type of] router [that] creates routees as child actors and removes them from the router if they terminate.

**Groups** are:

> [A type of] actor [where routees] are created externally to the router and the router sends messages to the specified path using actor selection, without watching for termination.

**Event Buses** are:

> ...a way to send messages to groups of actors

This sounds just like dispatchers and routers.

So my main concerns are:

- What is the difference between dispatchers, routers and event buses, and when to use each?
- When to use pool vs group?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

A **dispatcher** is basically a thread-pool. Akka uses dispatcher for multiple things (like enqueueing messages in the right mailbox or pick up a message from an actor mailbox and process it). Every time one of these actions need to be performed a thread from the thread-pool is selected and used for it. Akka comes by default with a `default-dispatcher` with the config you can find here in [reference.conf](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-actor/src/main/resources/reference.conf) searching for `default-dispatcher`. You are already using the `default-dispatcher` but you can define a different dispatcher to ensure you have a reserved thread-pool for other purposes (for example for the netty threads when using akka-remote or akka-cluster).

A **router** in Akka is an actor that uses some kind of routing logic to route messages to a list of routees. There are many types of router depending on the logic: Broadcast, Balancing, RoundRobin... you can find all of them in the akka docs. The routees of the router can be a pool or a group. One of the most popular use cases of routers is to vertically scale your app which means maximize the use of all the CPU available in your system (using multiple threads at the same time).

A **pool** means that the routees are being created on-demand for a given type. For example you may want a `RandomPool` of `MyFancyActor` with 3 instances. Akka will create three actors of `MyFancyActor` and a fourth one that will be the actual router. Every time the router actor gets a message will be forwarding the message to one of the 3 `MyFancyActor` actors. A pool takes care of restarting actors and watch their lifecycle to ensure you have n number of instances running.

A **group** means that the routees are being created before you are defining the router. Once you are defining your router you will need to pass a list of your routees actor that you previously created. A group will not monitor the lifecycle of your actors and you will need to do this yourself.

**Event buses** are channels where you can subscribe for a particular type of message with an actor. If there is a message of that particular type, you actor will get it. This is used for some Akka internals like subscribing to `DeadLetter`s when a message is unable to reach its destination or events regarding the formation of a cluster (in akka-cluster). You will use this to be aware of events happening in your `ActorSystem`.

Comment: Awesome answer, thanks @hveiga (+1) - a few followups real quick: (1) so it sounds like a `Dispatcher` is *like* a router, but used internally for messaging and other low-level thread stuff in Akka, and as such, I would never send a message directly to a Dispatcher, **yes**? (2) It sounds like an event bus is really like an actor system-wide mailbox. But if I have subscribed to receive a parrticular type of message from the bus, will that block other actors types from also receiving the same message? Thanks again!

Comment: `Dispatcher`s are transparent for you. They __dispatch__ threads to perform actions. You cannot send messages to a `dispatcher`. It's good to mention that a `dispatcher` is **not** an actor while a `router` is. Regarding event bus, you definition of kinda like a system-wide mailbox might be right. However, I don't know the internals but I really doubt that the Akka guys would make something blocking. I would assume it does not block. Probably is implemented as a `Router` where the list of routees (subscribers) for each type of message change over time.

Comment: Why would we need 3 instances of the same actor ? I thought there was only one instance of an Actor all the time ? and that the messages were passed to the actor by the Dispatcher ?

Comment: You might want more than 1 instance of the same actor. Since at a given point in time an actor can only process one message, there can be scenarios where you need to process multiple messages at the same time. The way of achieving this is having pool or groups of actors.

Comment: Thanks, @hveiga (+1) - I have a quick question that I wanted to follow up on. I'm curious to know how you arrived at the number "3" when recommending the size for the message processing pool. I understand that we might want to handle multiple messages at the same time, so it makes sense to create a pool that can handle the maximum number of messages we want to process in parallel. However, what happens if we make the pool too big, like say, 1000? Is it a waste of resources? And if so, can you explain why that is? I'd really appreciate it if you could elaborate on this a bit more? thanks