# What is the relation between Akka router and dispatcher?

Tags: scala, akka, actor

I am trying to learn Akka Actor system and while reading the documentation and example codes, I am a little bit confused about the difference and relation between Akka router and dispatcher. What I wonder is how does the router pool size affects the dispatcher configuration limits and vice versa. In Addition, I wonder how should a good dispatcher configuration be, which or what should be considered when defining dispatcher related configuration parameters (such as parallelism-min or parallelism-max) ?

Comment: This should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30633660/akka-messaging-mechanisms-by-example/30634989#30634989